# To deploy Play! 2 application on a path with its name at Apache or Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, deployment, playframework-2.0

How can I have my application made in **Play! 2.0.4** (latest "production ready" package) exported to run on either Apache 2.2 or Tomcat 6.0.18 at a path like e.g. `tomcatserver:8080/myApp/`?

The application always runs at `/` under `localhost:9000` on either Dev or Prod environment.

- I tried the `war` command but it seems unavailable for this version.
- Tried `stage` command, but it failed since it needs `chmod` and I'm using Windows XP (although my Apache is in a FreeBSD machine and Tomcat is in a Linux one).
- Then I tried `dist` command. It made the *myApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip*, but... I can't use it anywhere, its contents are structured in an unfamiliar way to the web servers.

Please, can someone share a light here on how to get it deployed on one of those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the [HTTP Fronted documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/HTTPServer), especially the Apache integration.

It should be something like:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
…
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName www.loadbalancedapp.com
  ProxyPass  /excluded !
  ProxyPass /myApp http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse /myApp http://127.0.0.1:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll need to deploy the Play application in [standalone mode](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ProductionDist), ie without any Java EE container (Tomcat & co). Play 2 core does not provide a way to generate a .war file.

If you want to absolutely use a Java EE container, take a look at the [play2-war-plugin](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin).